# Version Control for several projects

Tags: version-control, git

I've found several things about how to manage a data science projet with GIT  but I didn't find something about how to manage a set of projects.

In 90% of the case I'm working alone and over the month a lot of people ask me to check:

- the performance of our marketing operations
- the impact on sales of special period like christmas.
- clustering of our customers
- simple predictive models (churn,...)

**Here is my typical workflow for a single project:**

1. Prepare the data in SQL
2. Make descriptive  and predictive analysis in R/Python. I often use my own  library of code which I update over the time
3. Create output results in Markdown or powerpoint presentation.

**Here is the folder organisation for each project:**

1. Data

   - base
   - processed
2. R scripts
3. Python scripts
4. Outputs *(figures, markdown, powerpoint,...)*

And two libraries of code in R and Python that I use for all the analysis

**Question: In this case what is the best strategy ?**

1. A single repository with  all the analysis because the libraries are shared among several analysis ?

If yes, is it ok to have dozen of branches in the same repository like:

- `R_library_prod`
- `R_library_dev`
- `Python_library_prod`
- `Python_library_dev`
- `clustering_2015_prod`
- `clustering_2015_dev`
- `christmas_sales_analysis_prod`
- `christmas_sales_analysis_dev`
- *and so on*

  2. A repository for each project ? *(with potentially only 2 branches: prod and dev)*

If yes, how to manage the updates of the R and Python libraries ? Should I have a distinct repo for them and updates the libraries manually in the analytics projects repositories ?

Comment: FYI, I initially post thie question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781640/version-control-for-analytic-projects)

Comment: I would use 2; why don't you make the projects dependent on the libraries (you can specify specific versions, if that's what's needed)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please explain to me what do yoou mean by make the projects dependent on the libraries, I'm really new to this.

Comment: That's way too long for an answer! I suggest you start learning about *"dependency management"* - in Python, for example, you can define a `requirements.txt` file listing the libraries required for your project to run, or include them in a `setup.py`.

Comment: Have you looked into git submodules for option #2?